# Prove that $ \frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}=\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\cdot \frac{d\mu}{d\lambda},\text{ } \lambda\text{-a.e.} $

Tags: integration, measure-theory, derivatives, almost-everywhere, absolute-continuity

**Problem:**

Let $ \nu $ be a signed measure and $ \mu,\lambda $ be measures on $ (\Omega,\mathcal{F}) $ such that $ \lambda,\mu,\nu $ are $ \sigma $-finite, $ \nu\ll\mu $ and $ \mu \ll \lambda $. Prove that then,
$$ \dfrac{d\nu}{d\lambda}=\dfrac{d\nu}{d\mu}\cdot \dfrac{d\mu}{d\lambda},\text{ } \lambda\text{-a.e.} $$

**My proof:**

Since $ \nu \ll \mu $
$$ \nu (E)=\int_{E}fd\mu \text{ for } E\in\mathcal{F} $$
and since $ \mu \ll \lambda $
$$ \mu (E)=\int_{E}gd\lambda \text{  for  } E\in\mathcal{F}. $$
Combining these gives
$$ \nu (E)=\int_{E}fgd\lambda=\int_{E}hd\lambda \text{  for  } E\in\mathcal{F} $$
where $ h=fg $ $ \lambda $-a.e. Since
$$ f=\dfrac{d\nu}{d\mu}, $$
$$ g=\dfrac{d\mu}{d\lambda} $$
and
$$ h=\dfrac{d\nu}{d\lambda} $$
we get that
$$ \dfrac{d\nu}{d\lambda}=\dfrac{d\nu}{d\mu}\cdot \dfrac{d\mu}{d\lambda},\text{ } \lambda\text{-a.e.} $$

**Question:**

Is my proof correct? I have a strong feeling of that it is not correct. For example I don't really argue why the sentence starting with "Combining these gives" is true, and I don't even know if it is. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Indeed, the step "Combining these" is jumping without justification from the hypothesis to the desired conclusion, hence no this is not a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$ f=\dfrac{d\nu}{d\mu} \text{ and } g=\dfrac{d\mu}{d\lambda} $$ 
be measurable functions. Then $ f_+ $   and $ f_- $ are measurable (and non-negative), with 
$$ f=f_+-f_-. $$
We can therefore assume that $ f $ is non-negative. Let $ f_n $ be an increasing sequence of non-negative simple functions such that 
$$ f_n\to f. $$
Then
$$ \int_{E}f_n d\mu \to \int_{E}fd\mu$$
and 
$$ \int_{E}f_n gd\lambda \to \int_{E}fgd\lambda $$
for every measurable set $ E $. 
Let
$$ 1_F=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{for } x\in F\\
0 & \text{for } x\in \Omega\backslash F. \\
\end{cases}
$$
Since
\begin{align*}
\int_{E}1_Fd\mu &= \mu(E\cap F) \\
&= \int_{E\cap F}gd\lambda\\ &=\int_{E}1_Fgd\lambda
\end{align*}
for every measurable set $ F $, it follows that
$$ \int_{E}f_nd\mu=\int_{E}f_ngd\lambda $$
for each $ n $, and therefore that (using the  Randon-Nikodym theorem)
$$ \nu(E)=\int_{E}fd\mu=\int_{E}fgd\lambda $$
Hence
$$ \dfrac{d\nu}{d\lambda}=\dfrac{d\nu}{d\mu}\cdot \dfrac{d\mu}{d\lambda},\text{\space\space} \lambda\text{-a.e.} $$